# In Yii, is there a way to have urlFormat => path but still pass query params with an ampersand?

Tags: yii

Currently (in Yii 1.1.13) all `createUrl` methods put extra params in the 'path style', which means I cannot then override them by submitting a form, because they take precedence over those that come in a query string. Is there a way to always pass extra parameters in query string but still have the url look normal and not butt-ugly like with the `get` `urlFormat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`appendParams`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#appendParams-detail) to `false` in your `urlManager` component configuration.